# RCT_EXPORT_METHOD unknown argument type

Tags: objective-c, react-native, binding

I i try to bind my react code with an existing objective-C API. In my code i have:

```
#import "RcpRfidApi.h"

@implementation RcpRfidApi

// The React Native bridge needs to know our module
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(RcpRfidApi);

- (NSDictionary *)constantsToExport {
  return @{@"greeting": @"Welcome to the DevDactic\n React Native Tutorial!"};
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setReaderPower:(bool)on:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
  callback(@[[NSNull null], [NSNumber numberWithBool:on]]);
}
@end
```

but i have an error when i try to call my function on react

> Unknowm argument type '_Bool' in method .... Extend RCTConvert to support this type.

Answer (score 3):

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD() can only support **BOOL** or **NSNumber** for booleans.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem you maybe need to add a library to your project. Go in: Xcode > your project > Build Phases > Link binary with libraries.

In my case the Apple ExternalAccesory.framework was needed.